# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: reactivemongo/core/errors/ConnectionException

Tags: java, mongodb, reactive

OS: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

java: openjdk-18.0.2.1

I got the folowing error when trying to connect to a MongoDB database from ReactiveMongo API (reactivemongo_3-1.1.0-noshaded-RC6):

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: reactivemongo/core/errors/ConnectionException

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: reactivemongo/core/errors/ConnectionException
    at reactivemongo.api.AsyncDriver$.apply(AsyncDriver.scala:503)
    at e2m.MongoExport.<init>(MongoExport.scala:35)
    at e2m.MongoExport$.<clinit>(MongoExport.scala:82)
    at e2m.MongoExport.main(MongoExport.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: reactivemongo.core.errors.ConnectionException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 4 more
```

I looked for the package "reactivemongo.core.errors" inside the jar file and I did not found it.
Could you help me out by telling me which jar file should I include in my project to solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same error when I run "java -jar [MyJavaProgram.jar]" in which "MyJavaProgram.java" is included with another external jar file.